# iPad UIViewController loads as portrait when device is in landscape

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have an application with 3 view controllers.  They are all have shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation returning YES.  The first two, my main menu and my submenu both autorotate just fine.  The third viewcontroller, which programatically loads a UIImageView from a jpg file in the program's bundle, will only display in portrait.

In the viewcontroller containing the image, i have this:

```
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-00%d.jpg",setPrefix,imageNumber];

UIImageView *pictureView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];

pictureView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);

[self.view addSubview:pictureView];
```

and again, I have shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation returning YES for all orientations.

My image shows up, but is sideways, and the 0,0,1024,768 values I used to make my rectangle start from the top right corner going down, instead of starting at the top left and going across (holding in landscape).  Am I missing a parameter I need to set in order to ensure the imageview shows up in landscape instead of portrait?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but I suspect the setting of `pictureView.frame` may not be correct.  The frame can be "weird" (technical term) when adding a subview to an autorotated view.  See [Automatically Sizing UIView after Adding to Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659400/automatically-sizing-uiview-after-adding-to-window).